# Why don't desktop apps run under a client server model locally?

Tags: desktop

What if a typical desktop app like microsoft excel had a lightweight webserver and and the gui was implemented in html/css. You connected to your local excel server using a browser or html/css engine built into the OS. the heavy lifting is done by the webserver and the html/css just does GUI.

It would make the GUI part of porting apps to different platforms alot easier. Im pretty sure most apps dont need OS specific system calls for non GUI stuff?

Because each app is also a webserver, Your mate could connect to your excel server if you gave him permission and he could work on the same file. Every device would basically become a cloud provider allowing for easier collaboration.

You could also connect/sync with hosted versions of these apps like you do currently. Companies wouldn't could just develop a single app and use the same code for their cloud offering and their desktop offering.

Is there any glaring issues with this model eg. security? Can html/js even be used to talk effectively to programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X window server does exactly this. All programs running on top of it can be redirected to another computer. That being said, there are a lot of downsides to the approach:

•Sending display data over the network is expensive and slow compared with it being in the same address space.

•Now you have to worry about ports being open and all the headaches of network security.

•You have to write a lot of glue JavaScript and web-sockets to keep the program and GUI in sync and the program responsive.

•Your program has to be written in at least three more languages and needs to be tested in all versions of all browsers.

•The user now has to manage starting and stopping both a client and a server when they want to run a program.

There are a lot of high quality cross-platform GUI toolkits like QT, Swing or GTK. If you're like Google, you just build your own like they did with Chrome.